# Trying to make a ToggleButton with images, getting error: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-drawable, togglebutton

I am trying to follow a simple tutorial online about making a toggle button in android with images (so it shows images instad of ON/OFF).

It doesn't work. The error I get is

```
-        Binary XML file line #1: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and coding with Xamarin.

I have a toggle button defined like this in my **activity_main.xml**:

```
  <ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/toggleButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/toggleButton_emp"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButtonEmp"/>
```

Then I have a "**toggleButton_emp.xml**" file in "Resources\drawable" which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/faction4" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/faction3" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

faction4 and faction3 are valid drawables I have added to "Resources\drawable"

I have found many answers for this issue that are most 10 years old, and none help. They often say to make "drawable" first tag but it's already first. Or removing spaces but I don't have any.

Comment: "I am using Visual Studio 2019 and coding with Xamarin" -- it may be that either of those require different rules than do ordinary Android app projects. For example, you wrote that you put these things in "Resources\drawable", which would be wrong in an ordinary Android app project (it would be `res/drawable/` at best, and possibly in some other `res/` subdirectory).

Comment: @CommonsWare searching online I found no mention of these differences, everywhere I read it says to put drawable xmls, images, whatever - into that folder

Comment: Again, perhaps that is a Xamarin thing. Resources in standard Android projects go in `res/`, not `Resources/`. You will find that in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources). Most books on Android app development should cover this, such as [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-resourcetour-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack). But I have never worked with Xamarin (or Visual Studio 2019), so perhaps they do things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in this case it turned out the problem was that apparently either Android or Visual Studio does not accept .svg format (I assume the former). But there is no error message (format not supported?), no notice, nothing. So I assumed at this day an age, it should either accept it or barf in some way.

The error message I got was also not indicative of real problem in any way. It said that there is no drawable tag, while there clearly was one. So there was no way to guess drawable itself is the culprit.

Anyways, replacing ".svg"s with ".png"s fixed the issue.